# BlackBerry - MDS simulator init calls

Tags: blackberry

I debug my BlackBerry apps on device emulator, using the MDS simulator for access to the web.

Today I ran a Wireshark trace to catch my app's calls. I saw 2 calls made by the MDS simulator before my traffic started, and hope someone can explain them to me.

1. http://www.blackberry.net/go/mobile/mds/http/mappings.xml
2. http://www.blackberry.net/go/mobile/mds/http/mappings2prop.xsl

They seem to return some settings possibly for the simulator.

What are these calls for?

---

I also wonder if these calls are somehow related to the poor performance of the MDS simulator that I deal with regularly - will the MDS simulator continue to work if this server does not respond?

Hope this makes sense to one of the BB experts here - thx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have noticed this before, from my opinion i think it's a kind of request for blackberry server to open a port according to the proxy setting. Or it maybe as a log for connections. That is just my opinion I'm not an expert ...